# Which iOS presentation/slideshow app can be controlled by a Trust Wireless bluetooth remote

Tags: ios, bluetooth, remote-control

I want to use my iPhone (4S) with the VGA adapter to display presentations on a beamer (projector) and control the advancement with a [Trust Wireless Remote Control for iPad](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=17804).

The remote works well with music apps (iPod/Music, Rhapsody) and also in slideshow mode of the "Photos" app.

- Unfortunately iOS does not (yet) support QuickTime movies with manual advance - which would be my favorite option.
- Keynote for iOS unfortunately doesn't support generic bluetooth remotes (yet).

The best solution I've found so far is to use the "Photos" app and start a slideshow (of a group of images), which then can be controlled by the bluetooth remote.

Is there any app for presentations with the VGA adapter that supports bluetooth remotes?

<sup>As I have my iPhone with me anyway, I want to use as little (and least expensive) additional hardware as possible to give a presentation using a beamer with VGA input: the VGA out adapter and the bluetooth remote are working with my iPhone - I'm only missing a decent presentation app that supports both.</sup>

<sup>I would prefer a non-jailbreak solution that is likely to be compatible with new devices/iOS versions.</sup>

Comment: I just bought Keynote and it doesn't work with my bluetooth remote. [Slides](http://itunes.apple.com/app/slides/id392535591?mt=8) has no bluetooth support and [2Screens](http://itunes.apple.com/app/2screens-for-iphone/id440278704?l=en&mt=8) does work with bluetooth keyboards but not with my remote.

Comment: [Presentation Viewer for iPhone](http://www.zuhanden.de/apps/presentation-viewer/) also doesn't support bluetooth remotes.

Comment: Have you tried talking to the technical support staff at the Trust.com company and asking them which apps support their product? I'll bet they have a list.

Comment: @Wheat Williams: Good idea, I just contacted them - let's see if they have a good suggestion.

Comment: This is what Trust's Customer Care wrote back: «Trust Wireless Remote Control has been developed for for iPad, therefore we can not confirm compatibility with iPhone.
Wireless Remote Control for iPad will work with generic multimedia applications of iPad, and not fully suitable for the presentations.»

Comment: So what you're looking for is a way to give a presentation (slides are beamed from your iPhone) and you need to go through your slides without having to touch your iPhone, right?

Comment: @Michiel: I wanna use a projector (similar to [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H6309LL/A#tech-specs) ), but the available beamer/projector only supports VGA-input; thus, beaming by e.g. WLAN is unfortunately not an option. And of course I could add more expensive hardware like an iPad or AppleTV, which I connect to the projector. But I want to keep the package as small and least expensive as possible - which in I my imagination would be: iPhone + VGA-adapter + bluetooth remote + presentation app ; and the only thing missing is the app

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2012 there doesn't seem to be a real presenter app for the iPhone, which supports the Trust Wireless Remote Control (or generic bluetooth remotes, that do work with music apps) and offers VGA-out.

I really hoped I didn't search thoroughly enough but it seems such an app has yet to be made - and I bet it would sell well.

So, if anyone happens to find such an app for the iPhone or something that supports QuickTime movies with manual advance: please post it here and I'm gonna reward a bounty of ≥150 points.

The best way to go till then: Use a collection of pictures in slideshow mode of the "Photos" app (supports both VGA-out and bluetooth remotes)

Answer (score 0):

Although it works with your music, your Bluetooth remote is only supported with the iPad 1 and 2. While similar, Keynote for iPad iOS 5.0.1 DOES support Bluetooth remotes.

An alternative would be to use another iOS 5.0.1 device (iPhone, iPad) and use Keynote Remote over WiFi or Bluetooth. WiFi is easy, Bluetooth is missing a bit of information.
For Bluetooth, create a Bluetooth personal hotspot and pair the devices together. Then Keynote and Keynote Remote work fine. You set up the personal hotspot by going to the Bluetooth settings on both devices and they search for each other, etc. – it's pretty clear.

Comment: As mentioned in my question: this bluetooth remote works perfectly fine with my iPhone. Keynote on iOS supports the ["Keynote Remote"](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH1350) app, which works via bluetooth but requires a second iOS device. Apparently iOS-Keynote does not support «generic» bluetooth remotes (at least that's what I read in the comments on iTunes).

Answer (score 0):

**(Read my edit first...)**
Apparently, when your update your iPhone 4S to 5.1, you can reconnect with your  Bluetooth device...

[They say:](http://www.themobilepresenter.com/article.php/bluetooth-remote-control)

> As discussed in the comments below, Apple broke the Bluetooth
>   connectivity in Keynote in iOS 5.0 and 5.0.1 [...]
>   The good news is that they fixed it again in iOS 5.1

I hope this helps for you!

**EDIT:**
Nevermind, they are talking about Keynote Remote and using Keynote between an iPhone and an iPad. Try updating to 5.1 anyway, maybe it helps...

Comment: I tried Keynote on iOS 5.1, but still no support for my/generic bluetooth remotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sliderocket](http://www.sliderocket.com/signup/), and see if your bluetooth remote is supported.

Try [Eprojector](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eprojector/id377193830?mt=8)
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eprojector/id377193830?mt=8
But your bluetooth remote will probably not work.

Comment: Didn't know Sliderocket (seems to be iPad only), looked into Eprojector before - sadly, both without support for bluetooth remotes.