# Need a Presenter for the iPad 

Tags: ipad, keynote

I'm using my iPad to show several presentations. I use the Apple Keynote App. But it's not handy to run back to the iPad and flip to the next slide.

> Is there any Hardware-Presenter (Bluetooth) for the iPad which works fine with the Keynote App?

There are quite a few for the Macintosh, but do they also work with the iPad?

There's an App for the iPhone, i know, but i haven't one at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems Keynote for iOS does not support generic bluetooth remotes.

See this question and the answers: [Which iOS presentation/slideshow app can be controlled by a Trust Wireless bluetooth remote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/42749/14994)